# Obtain IP in AWS Cognito Pre Authentication Lambda Trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, amazon-cognito

I'm logging my users via Azure AD using SAML as a federation provider, I wanted to know if it's possible to receive the ip at this point. If so how.

Answer (score 3):

I have so far not found a direct way to enable the IP address to be sent to the lambda.

What we know is that the pre-authentication lambda will receive such data, from Cognito:

```
{
  version: '1',
  region: '-----------',
  userPoolId: '-----------',
  userName: '--------------',
  callerContext: {
    awsSdkVersion: 'aws-sdk-unknown-unknown',
    clientId: '----------------'
  },
  triggerSource: 'PreAuthentication_Authentication',
  request: {
    userAttributes: {
      sub: '-------------',
      'cognito:email_alias': '----------------,
      'cognito:user_status': 'CONFIRMED',
      email_verified: 'true',
      email: '--------------------'
    },
    validationData: {
      myCustomPropertiesLikeAnIpAddress: 'anIpAddress'
    }
  },
  response: {}
}
```

As we can see, the IP address is not contained within.
However, we could leverage the "validationData" property, which is a collection of other properties, that can be set from the client.

One such property could be the IP address.

Now we need to somehow obtain this IP address and send it to the lambda.

One way I found to obtain the IP address in a client application, is by making a GET request to https://geolocation-db.com/json/ (or a request to any other IP providers)

The response will look like this

```
Current IP Address: myIpAddress
```

Simply clean up the response the way you see fit, then add it to your cognito log in request.

There is a risk for altering the client's code, and not sending, or sending a modified IP address, which, depending on how important this is, you could validate on the lambda itself.
You have to see, really, how motivated would somebody be, to do such a modification.

Comment: We really cared about the client no being able to spoof the ip address. At the en we ended up doing the validation in other point of our system. We did it in the authorizer  https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/compute/using-enhanced-request-authorizers-in-amazon-api-gateway/ In the end this was simpler and satisfied our security needs, simply in the frontend we would do a request to our system and if it failed we wouldn't even show the login. ( and even if they logged in, they wouldn't have access to anything because of the authorizer )

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is using AWS WAF (Web Application Firewall), see this [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html)

In WAF you can create a Web ACL by following these steps:

- Create a new Web ACL in the same region you have Cognito deployed
- Associate this WEB ACL to your Cognito User Pool
- Add a rule with the following matching criteria:

  - Inspect: Originates from an IP Address In
  - IP Set: Create and Associate to the IP set you want to allow traffic
  - Action: Allow
  - Set the default action to block
- Organize priorities and create

This way, every HTTP(S) request made to Cognito will first be filtered by WAF, if it matches the IP Rule you created traffic will be allowed, otherwise it will be Forbidden (403 status code)